# Profile icon in the Navbar that reloads automatically (Angular)

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a navbar that, when a user logs in, the "Log in" link is modified by that user's profile icon. The problem occurs when you log in, the navbar reloads but the profile icon does not appear until you manually reload the entire page with an F5.

```
 <li *ngIf="_usuarioService.estaLogueado() == true" class="dropdown nav-item dropleft">
        <a href="#" class=" nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <div *ngIf="user" class="photo">
            <img [src]="user.foto | imagen" alt="Profile Photo" width="35" height="35">
          </div>
```

They tell me, as a solution, to remove the navbar as a generic component of the application and put it on all pages so that it is reloaded with them. But my question is if there is any way to make it reload that particular icon, when logging in.

The component code:

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( public _usuarioService: UsuarioService) { }
  user:Usuario;

  ngOnInit() {
    this._usuarioService.cargarStorage();

    this._usuarioService.getUser(localStorage.getItem('id'))
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.user = data;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: You haven't included your component code, but in general you don't need to remove the navbar as a generic component and put in all pages. you are doing it the right way.
You need to subscribe to the user data changes after the login, probably from a service and update the navbar on changes. add some more code so we could understand what you did wrong.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: @Ineludible Can you please post the code of estaLogueado() method?

Answer (score 0):

When your view is initalized and the user is not logged in yet this condition `_usuarioService.estaLogueado() == true` is correctly `false`, so the `<li>` element and its content is not rendered.

When you log in, the navbar component is not destroyed and rebuild so the condition `_usuarioService.estaLogueado() == true` is not evaluated again.

When you refresh your page the component DOES get destroyed and then intiliazed so the condition is checked once again and this time (since the user is logged in ) `_usuarioService.estaLogueado()` returns true. That's why you see this behavior.

There are many ways you can tackle this behavior, but the approach I would suggest is using observables, in order to listen to changes at the users log in status.

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znvhtf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.html) small example might give you an idea.